# Return Query Results to Textbox on Userform

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-forms

let me start by giving you some table structures.  I have a 3 relevant tables:

- OutreachEventsLog: stores information like Date/Time/Location for community events

  ```
  | EventID | Date     | Location |...
  | 1       |2/19/2019 | Earth    |
  | 2       |2/18/2019 | Earth    |
  ```
- Staff: A list of staff employed in program

  ```
  |StaffID  | First Name | Last Name | Full Name  |
  | 1       | John       | Smith     | John Smith |
  | 2       | Mary       | Sue       | Mary Sue   | 
  | 3       | Betty      | Jane      | Betty Jane |
  ```
- OutreachEventtoStaff: a junction table that relates staff members to the outreach events they attended.

  ```
  | Event Id | Staff ID |
  | 1        | 1        |
  | 1        | 2        |
  | 2        | 1        |
  | 2        | 2        |
  | 2        | 3        |
  ```

I've created a couple of forms to capture event information.  The two relevant ones are called OutreachSummary and EventtoStaff.  The EventtoStaff form is launched by clicking a button entitled "Add Staff" embedded in the OutreachSummary form.  This process is working properly and updating all associated tables correctly.

Here's what I want to do: I want to embed a text box on the OutreachSummary form that lists all the staff members currently assigned to that event, with entries separated by a comma.  Example: "John Smith, Mary Sue, Betty Jane..." where Event ID = 2

I've managed to write some code that returns a comma delimited list like the one above to a query.  I then tried grab a specific row from this query based on EventID and assign it to the text box with no luck.  I keep getting a ?Name error.  Is there an easy way to do this?  Am I even on the right track?

Thanks for the input!

Comment: Exactly how do you try to 'grab' row - DLookup()? You can call the concatenation function from textbox ControlSource.

Comment: Please post the code for the function you are using to create your concatenated string, and show how you are calling such function within the ControlSouce of your textbox.